# Why are my views inside the storyboard tableViewHeader visually misplaced?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode8

When adding a tableview header in storyboard, by dragging a view onto the header area, subviews inside this header view seem to be visually misplaced. Is there a logical reason for this?

Reproducing the problem (Xcode 8):

1. Open storyboard
2. Drag a UITableViewController onto the canvas
3. Drag a UIView onto the tableview header area

[image: TableViewHeader in storyboard]

4. Add any view as a subview on the header view:

[image: This view should be placed at the top of the header view]

This issue is only visible in storyboard though. At runtime, the views are aligned as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix: Dont drag in there, drag it on the above like this, since you treat it as a view property to the view controller, not to it's view, when you drag into the view, it will treat your header view as a subview to the content view, that's not what you need

[image]

Comment: I see, but how does the tableViewHeader connection take place? Do you add an outlet of your "floating storyboard view" to the respected view controller and set the tableViewHeader property with the outlet?

Comment: Yes, just create iboutlet for that view and set it with code, this way also good for subview that you want it appear occasionally, since it wont messed up with your current design

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also applies to xib. When you drag views which the Simulated Metrics size is freedform onto tableView, system will treat the first subview as tableHeaderView, the second subview as tableFooterView automatically.